# How to solve this trig integral?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I tried to solve this integral but I don't know how. Can someone help me please?
$$\int _0^2\frac{\arctan \left(3x\right)}{x}dx\:$$
Thanks for any possible response.

*Edit:* My trial:
1. Substitution:
$$\int _0^2\frac{\arctan \left(3x\right)}{x}dx\: = 9\int _0^2\:\:\frac{\arctan \left(u\right)}{u}du = (2.IBP => dv = \frac{1}{u}, v = \log _e\left(u\right); q = \arctan \left(u\right), dq= \frac{1}{1+u^2}) = 9(\log _e\left(u\right)\arctan \left(u\right) -  \int _0^2 \frac{1}{1+u^2}\log _e\left(u\right)) = (3.IBP => dv = \frac{1}{1+u^2}) , v =  \arctan \left(u\right); q = \log _e\left(u\right), dq= \frac{1}{u}) = 9(\log _e\left(u\right)\arctan \left(u\right) -( \arctan \left(u\right)\log _e\left(u\right) - \int _0^2 \arctan \left(u\right)\frac{1}{u} $$
As you can see I arrived at the same thing.

Comment: The function $\frac{\arctan x}{x}$ does not have an elementary antiderivative (it depends on the dilogarithm) and the radius of convergence of the Taylor series at $x=0$ is only $1$.

Comment: Please try to include information about your experience level so people know how to best answer you. I have answered similar questions in the past and had my answers flat out rejected because I assumed that the OP knew things which they in fact did not. For instance, do you know the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus? Do you know any real analysis? Anything about special functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\frac{\arctan x}{x}$ does not have an elementary antiderivative, and the radius of convergence of its Taylor series at $x=0$ is just one, so we need a couple of tricks.

1. $$\int_{0}^{2}\frac{\arctan(3x)}{x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{6}\frac{\arctan x}{x}\,dx = \log(6)\arctan(6)-\int_{0}^{6}\frac{\log(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx$$
2. $$ \int_{0}^{6}\frac{\log(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx = -\int_{1/6}^{+\infty}\frac{\log(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx=\int_{0}^{1/6}\frac{\log(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx$$
3. $$ \int_{0}^{1/6}x^{2k}\log(x)\,dx = -\frac{1+(2k+1)\log 6}{6^{2k+1}(2k+1)^2}$$

give:

> $$ \int_{0}^{2}\frac{\arctan(3x)}{x}\,dx = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}\log(6)+\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k}{6^{2k+1}(2k+1)^2}}.$$

Comment: I asked about the details here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824759/int-06-frac-logx1x2-dx

Answer (score 2):

Enforce the substitution $u=3x$ to get:

$$\int_{0}^{6} \frac{\arctan u}{u} du$$

Now use the identity found in Wikipedia https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions (scroll down to logarithmic forms) :

$$\arctan x=\frac{1}{2}i [\ln(1-ix)-\ln(1+ix)]$$

So

$$\frac{\arctan (x)}{x}= \frac{-1}{2} [\frac{\ln (1-ix)}{ix} - \frac{\ln (1+ix)}{ix}]$$

Use this to transform the integral to:

$$\frac{-1}{2} \int_{0}^{6} [\frac{\ln (1-ix)}{ix} - \frac{\ln (1+ix)}{ix}] dx$$

Now the substitution $t=ix$, $-idt=dx$ to get:

$$\frac{i}{2} \int_{0}^{6i} [\frac{\ln (1-t)}{t} -\frac{\ln (1+t)}{t}] dt$$

Let's look at:

$$\int_{0}^{6i} \frac{\ln (1+t)}{t} dt$$

Enforce the substitution $t=-w$:

$$\int_{0}^{-6i} \frac{\ln (1-w)}{w} dw$$

Note the dilogarithm is defined as:

$$\textrm{Li}_2(z)=\int_{z}^{0} \frac{\ln (1-t)}{t} dt$$

So this integral is equal to:

$$-\textrm{Li}_2(-6i)$$

The other integral is,

$$\int_{0}^{6i} \frac{\ln (1-t)}{t} dt=-\textrm{Li}_2(6i)$$

So your integral is equal to,

$$\frac{i}{2}[-\textrm{Li}_2(6i)+\textrm{Li}_2(-6i)]$$

Please correct me if you see anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest integration by parts. Hard to integrate arctan(3x) when its derivative isn't popping up anywhere in the integrand. So integration by parts using arctan(3x) = u, dx/x = dv. I realize this will get an ln. Might take a couple of IBP before the solution falls out.

Comment: Ah seems like that gives you an integrand of ln(x)/(1+x^2), so maybe better to use u = 1/x, dv = arctan(3x). Might be painful but could work out in the end.

Comment: Painful isn't the word for that substitution choice. I don't think there IS a nice,easy way to do this without a computer algebra system.

Comment: Hard to disagree with ya. I tried using 3x = tan(theta), too, and that doesn't look manageable either...

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the integral like this:

$$\int _0^2 \frac {1}{x}\arctan(3x)\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}$$

Then we just use integration by parts to solve. Here,I'll get you started:

$u = \arctan(3x)$

$\mathop{\mathrm{d}u} = \dfrac{1} {1+x^2}\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}$

$\mathop{\mathrm{d}v} = \dfrac {1}{x}\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}$

$v  = \ln x$

Then:

$$\int u \mathop{\mathrm{d}v} = uv - \int v \mathop{\mathrm{d}u} = \arctan(3x) \ln x - \int_0^2\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2} \mathop{\mathrm{d}x}$$

We now repeat until we obtain the desired integral.

Comment: I don't also think that integration by parts works. There's gotta be another way. Btw I tried IBP again but I got a result too complicated to be handled.