# Evaluating $ \int_{0}^{6}\frac{\log(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to understand an answer by @Jack D' Aurizio.

This is the part I get lost on:

$$ \int_{0}^{6}\frac{\log(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx = -\int_{1/6}^{+\infty}\frac{\log(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx=\int_{0}^{1/6}\frac{\log(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx$$

What is going on here? I think Jack first does the substitution $u=\frac{1}{x}$ but then I'm lost.

Also Jack says,

$$ \int_{0}^{1/6}x^{2k}\log(x)\,dx = -\frac{1+(2k+1)\log 6}{6^{2k+1}(2k+1)^2}$$

Again I don't understand what's happening.

Comment: 1st equality is okay. But shouldn't there be $\infty$ instead of $0$  in the lower limit of the 3rd value?

Comment: Second one is integration by parts

Comment: It would help to provide the link, which seems to be http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1823412/how-to-solve-this-trig-integral/1823637#1823637 (and why don't you post a comment there asking him?).

Comment: For the second equality in the first line, consider the integral I from 0 to $\infty$ and observe by substituting $x=1/u$ that $I=-I$, i.e. $I=0$.

Comment: @BarryCipra  that's the one. I just want there to be space so he can answer neatly. I'm not really good with answers like "integration by parts" or something of that nature. I have to see the details.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Have you *tried* to do the integration by parts yourself? With pen and paper, integrating the $x^{2k}$ and deriving the $\log x$? This is the best way to "see the details."

Comment: Thanks I got the second one now. Now what would you suggest I do for the first one @ClementC.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla, fair enough.  You might then post a link to *this* question as a comment to the answer there so that Jack (and others) will be sure to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the integral

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^6 \frac{\log(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx+\int_6^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Enforcing the substitution $x\to 1/x$ in integrals on the right-hand side of $(1)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_{\infty}^{1/6}\frac{\log(1/x)}{1+1/x^2}\,\left(\frac{-1}{x^2}\right)\,dx+\int_{1/6}^{0}\frac{\log(1/x)}{1+1/x^2}\,\left(\frac{-1}{x^2}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\int_{\infty}^{1/6}\frac{\log(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx+\int_{1/6}^{0}\frac{\log(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\\\
&=-\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\\\
&=-I
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we find that $I=0$ from which we see that

$$\int_{1/6}^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx=-\int_0^{1/6}\frac{\log(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx$$

Answer (score 1):

Start with the integral $I(k)$ as given by

$$I(k)=\int_0^{1/6}x^{2k}\log(x)\,dx \tag 1$$

Now, integrating by parts $(1)$ with $u=\log(x)$ and $v=\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
I(k)&=-\log(6)\frac{(1/6)^{2k+1}}{2k+1}-\frac{1}{2k+1}\int_0^{1/6} x^{2k}\,dx\\\\
&=-\log(6)\frac{(1/)6^{2k+1}}{2k+1}-\frac{(1/6)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)^2}\\\\
&=-\frac{\left(\log(6)(2k+1)+1\right)}{6^{2k+1}(2k+1)^2}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, note that

$$\begin{align}
-\int_{1/6}^\infty{\log x\over1+x^2}dx=\int_0^{1/6}{\log x\over1+x^2}dx
&\iff0=\int_0^{1/6}{\log x\over1+x^2}dx+\int_{1/6}^\infty{\log x\over1+x^2}dx\\
&\iff0=\int_0^\infty{\log x\over1+x^2}dx\\
&\iff0=\int_0^1{\log x\over1+x^2}dx+\int_1^\infty{\log x\over1+x^2}dx\\
&\iff-\int_1^\infty{\log x\over1+x^2}dx=\int_0^1{\log x\over1+x^2}dx
\end{align}$$

The substitution $u=1/x$ establishes the last line.